# Why will std::rel_ops::operators be deprecated in C++20?

Tags: c++, standards, deprecated, std, c++20

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp), `std::rel_ops::operator!=,>,<=,>=` will be deprecated in C++20.

What's the rationale behind?

Comment: Probably because three-way comparison is adopted for C++20.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is operator!= removed in C++20 for many standard library types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319928/why-is-operator-removed-in-c20-for-many-standard-library-types)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In C++20, you get [three-way comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison) (operator `<=>`), which automatically "generates" [default comparisons](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) if provided:

```
struct A {
   // You only need to implement a single operator.
   std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const A&) const;
};

// Compiler generates 4 relational operators (you need to default the
// three-way comparison operator to get == and !=).
A to1, to2;
if (to1 > to2) { /* ... */ } // ok
if (to1 <= to2) { /* ... */ } // ok, single call to <=>
```

There are multiple advantages of the three-way comparison over `std::rel_ops`, which is probably why `std::rel_ops` operators are deprecated. On top of my head:

- It is more versatile, since, depending on the return type of `operator<=>` (`std::strong_ordering`, `std::weak_ordering`, ...), only relevant operators are generated. See the [`<compare>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/compare) header for more information.
- You do not bring a bunch of templated operator overloads by doing `using namespace std::rel_ops`.
- You can ask the compiler to generate the three-way operator for you by defaulting it (`auto operator<=>(A const&) = default`) — This will basically generate a lexicographic comparison of base classes and non-static data members, plus it will deduce the right type of ordering if the return type is `auto`.

Comment: cant help myself, but "spaceship operator" sounds so much cooler than "three-way-comparison" :P

Comment: As I understand it it will not even be necessary in most cases to implement `<=>`. Instead one will be able to write `std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const TotallyOrdered& that) const = default;`

Comment: @sv90 Yes, you're right, I've added a bullet in the list of advantages ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I guess too many [potential] operators turned out to resemble spacecraft ;-)

Comment: With a document cleverly titled "<=> != =="[1], one will not get "operator==" from an "operator<=>", unless operator<=> is defaulted.

[1] Which can be translated to Python as "\_\_cmp\_\_ is not \_\_eq\_\_"

Comment: @MarcinZdun Thanks for the precision, but I don't know what you tried to do with the link but the document you cited is not accessible.

Comment: Well, I didn't make any actual reference to a particular document. The "[1]" was a reference to a tongue-in-cheek Python "translation" on how to read the title in the same note. I just didn't know comments do not keep the newlines which slightly destroyed the joke. If you are interested, the actual document is [P1185R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r1.html)

Comment: @L.F. I'm lost. I thought this is exactly, what I've said. Did you want to re-phrase my comment?

Comment: @MarcinZdun I'm sorry, I missed the "unless operator<=> is defaulted" part. Perhaps I've been damaged by the virus ...

Answer (score 14):

> What's the rationale behind?

`rel_ops` was deprecated by [Library Support for the Spaceship (Comparison) Operator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0768r1.pdf). The paper doesn't list any motivation, but it does appear in the [spaceship paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r2.pdf):

> This subsumes namespace `std::rel_ops`, so we propose also removing (or deprecating) `std::rel_ops`.

There are four reasons mentioned in the paper (including correctness and performance). But one big one not mentioned in either paper is that `std::rel_ops` just... doesn't work. Rule of thumb is that operators are found using ADL. `rel_ops` doesn't give you ADL-findable operators, it just declares unconstrained function templates like:

```
namespace std {
    namespace rel_ops {
        template< class T >
        bool operator!=( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) 
        {
            return !(lhs == rhs);
        }
    }    
}
```

So using algorithms like:

```
struct X { ... };
bool operator<(X const&, X const&) { ... };
std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), std::greater<>{});
```

Just doesn't work, unless you make sure to:

```
#include <utility>
using namespace std::rel_ops;
```

Fairly consistently everywhere as your first include to ensure that these operators are visible at the point of definition of every function template you could possibly call.

So `operator<=>` is just strictly superior:

- It actually works.
- You only have to write one function (`<=>`) instead of two (`==` and `<`)
- Typically, you actually have to write zero functions (`= default`)
- Did I mention it actually works?

Answer (score 3):

C++20 provides [Three way comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) thus the unique ones will become deprecated.