# Why is operator!= removed in C++20 for many standard library types?

Tags: c++, std, comparison-operators, c++20, equality-operator

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp), `std::type_info::operator!=` gets removed with C++20, however, `std::type_info::operator==` apparently remains.

What's the reasoning behind? I might agree on comparing for inequality being meaningless, but then comparing for equality would be just as meaningless as well, wouldn't it?

Similarly, `operator!=` of many other standard library types, including containers such as [`std::unordered_map::operator!=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp) and [`std::unordered_set::operator!=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/operator_cmp) will be removed in C++20 according to cppreference.

Having to write `if(!(id1 == id2))` doesn't make any code any clearer compared to `if(id1 != id2)`, in contrast, just the opposite...

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In C++20 the way that the relational operators work was changed, notably with the introduction of the spaceship `<=>` operator. In particular, If you only provide `operator==`, then `a != b` is rewritten to `!(a == b)`.

From [[over.match.oper]/3.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4):

> The rewritten candidate set is determined as follows:
>
> - For the relational ([expr.rel]) operators, the rewritten candidates include all non-rewritten candidates for the expression x <=> y.
> - For the relational ([expr.rel]) and three-way comparison ([expr.spaceship]) operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y <=> x.
> - **For the != operator ([expr.eq]), the rewritten candidates include all non-rewritten candidates for the expression x == y.**
> - For the equality operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y == x.
> - For all other operators, the rewritten candidate set is empty.

And [[over.match.oper]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4):

> If a rewritten operator== candidate is selected by overload resolution for an operator @, its return type shall be cv bool, and x @ y is interpreted as:
>
> - if @ is != and the selected candidate is a synthesized candidate with reversed order of parameters, !(y == x),
> - **otherwise, if @ is !=, !(x == y)**,
> - otherwise (when @ is ==), y == x,
>
> in each case using the selected rewritten operator== candidate.

As such, an explicit overload for `operator!=` is no longer necessary. The removal of the operator has not changed comparison semantics.

All containers have had their `operator!=` removed, as far as I can tell (check e.g. [the vector synopsis](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.syn)). The only exceptions are the container adaptors `std::queue` and `std::stack`: my guess is that it is to preserve backwards compatibility when used with third-party containers, in case the equality operators are not symmetric.

Comment: [p1614](https://wg21.link/p1614) may be of interest as well, as I believe that was the proposal that removed the overloads.

Answer (score 44):

We don't need a library provided `operator!=` anymore. Providing `operator==` allows the compiler to do some juggling and evaluate `a != b` in terms of `a == b`, all on its own.

> **[over.match.oper]**
>
> [3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3) For a unary operator @ with an operand of a type whose
>   cv-unqualified version is T1, and for a binary operator @ with a left
>   operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is T1 and a right
>   operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is T2, four sets of
>   candidate functions, designated member candidates, non-member
>   candidates, built-in candidates, and rewritten candidates, are
>   constructed as follows:
>
> [3.4.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4.3) For the != operator ([expr.eq]), the rewritten candidates
>   include all non-rewritten candidates for the expression x == y.

`std::type_info` and many more library types had their `operator!=` removed as part of [P1614 - The Mothership has Landed](http://wg21.link/p1614).