# Breaking change in C++20 or regression in clang-trunk/gcc-trunk when overloading equality comparison with non-Boolean return value?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, eigen, eigen3, c++20

The following code compiles fine with clang-trunk in c++17 mode but breaks in c++2a (upcoming c++20) mode:

```
// Meta struct describing the result of a comparison
struct Meta {};

struct Foo {
    Meta operator==(const Foo&) { return Meta{}; }
    Meta operator!=(const Foo&) { return Meta{}; }
};

int main()
{
    Meta res = (Foo{} != Foo{});
}
```

It also compiles fine with gcc-trunk or clang-9.0.0: https://godbolt.org/z/8GGT78

The error with clang-trunk and `-std=c++2a`:

```
<source>:12:19: error: use of overloaded operator '!=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'Foo' and 'Foo')
    Meta res = (f != g);
                ~ ^  ~
<source>:6:10: note: candidate function
    Meta operator!=(const Foo&) {return Meta{};}
         ^
<source>:5:10: note: candidate function
    Meta operator==(const Foo&) {return Meta{};}
         ^
<source>:5:10: note: candidate function (with reversed parameter order)
```

I understand that C++20 will make it possible to only overload `operator==` and the compiler will automatically generate `operator!=` by negating the result of `operator==`. As far as I understand, this only works as long as the return type is `bool`.

The source of the problem is that in Eigen we declare a set of operators `==`, `!=`, `<`, ... between `Array` objects or `Array` and Scalars, which return (an expression of) an Array of `bool` (which can then be accessed element-wise, or used otherwise). E.g.,

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
int main()
{
    Eigen::ArrayXd a(10);
    a.setRandom();
    return (a != 0.0).any();
}
```

In contrast to my example above this even fails with gcc-trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/RWktKs.
I have not managed yet to reduce this to a non-Eigen example, which fails in both clang-trunk and gcc-trunk (the example at the top is quite simplified).

Related issue report: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/issues/1833

My actual question: Is this actually a breaking change in C++20 (and is there a possibility to overload the comparison operators to return Meta-objects), or is it more likely a regression in clang/gcc?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319928/why-is-operator-removed-in-c20-for-many-standard-library-types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Eigen issue appears to reduce to the following:

```cpp
using Scalar = double;

template<class Derived>
struct Base {
    friend inline int operator==(const Scalar&, const Derived&) { return 1; }
    int operator!=(const Scalar&) const;
};

struct X : Base<X> {};

int main() {
    X{} != 0.0;
}
```

The two candidates for the expression are

1. the rewritten candidate from `operator==(const Scalar&, const Derived&)`
2. `Base<X>::operator!=(const Scalar&) const`

Per [[over.match.funcs]/4](https://wg21.link/over.match.funcs#4), as `operator!=` was not imported into the scope of `X` by a *using-declaration*, the type of the implicit object parameter for #2 is `const Base<X>&`. As a result, #1 has a better implicit conversion sequence for that argument (exact match, rather than derived-to-base conversion). Selecting #1 then renders the program ill-formed.

Possible fixes:

- Add `using Base::operator!=;` to `Derived`, or
- Change the `operator==` to take a `const Base&` instead of a `const Derived&`.

Comment: Is there a reason why the actual code couldn't return a `bool` from their `operator==`? Because that seems to be the only reason the code is ill-formed under the new rules.

Comment: The actual code involves an `operator==(Array, Scalar)` that does element-wise comparison and return an `Array` of `bool`. You can't turn that into a `bool` without breaking everything else.

Comment: This seems a bit like a defect in the standard. The rules for rewriting `operator==` weren't supposed to affect existing code, yet they do in this case, because the check for a `bool` return value is not part of selecting candidates for rewriting.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The general principle being followed is that the check is for whether you *can* do something (*e.g.*, invoke the operator), not whether you *should*, to avoid having implementation changes silently affect the interpretation of other code.  It turns out that rewritten comparisons break a lot of things, but mostly things that were already questionable and are easy to fix.  So, for better or for worse, these rules were adopted anyway.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, I guess your solution will resolve our issue (I don't have time to install gcc/clang trunk with reasonable effort at the moment, so I will just check if this breaks anything up to the latest stable compiler versions).

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the code in fact breaks in C++20.

The expression `Foo{} != Foo{}` has three candidates in C++20 (whereas there was only one in C++17):

```
Meta operator!=(Foo& /*this*/, const Foo&); // #1
Meta operator==(Foo& /*this*/, const Foo&); // #2
Meta operator==(const Foo&, Foo& /*this*/); // #3 - which is #2 reversed
```

This comes from the new *rewritten candidate* rules in [[over.match.oper]/3.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4). All of those candidates are viable, since our `Foo` arguments are not `const`. In order to find the best viable candidate, we  have to go through our tiebreakers.

The relevant rules for best viable function are, from [[over.match.best]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#2):

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then
>
> - [... lots of irrelevant cases for this example ...] or, if not that, then
> - F2 is a rewritten candidate ([over.match.oper]) and F1 is not
> - F1 and F2 are rewritten candidates, and F2 is a synthesized candidate with reversed order of parameters and F1 is not

`#2` and `#3` are rewritten candidates, and `#3` has reversed order of parameters, while `#1` is not rewritten. But in order to get to that tiebreaker, we need to first get through that initial condition: *for all arguments* the conversion sequences are not worse.

`#1` is better than `#2` because all the conversion sequences are the same (trivially, because the function parameters are the same) and `#2` is a rewritten candidate while `#1` is not.

But... both pairs `#1`/`#3` and `#2`/`#3`  get stuck on that first condition. In both cases, the first parameter has a better conversion sequence for `#1`/`#2` while the second parameter has a better conversion sequence for `#3` (the parameter that is `const` has to undergo an extra `const` qualification, so it has a worse conversion sequence). This `const` flip-flop causes us to not be able to prefer either one.

As a result, the whole overload resolution is ambiguous.

> As far as I understand, this only works as long as the return type is `bool`.

That's not correct. We unconditionally consider rewritten and reversed candidates. The rule we have is, from [[over.match.oper]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#9):

> If a rewritten `operator==` candidate is selected by overload resolution for an operator `@`, its return type shall be *cv* `bool`

That is, we still consider these candidates. But if the best viable candidate is an `operator==` that returns, say, `Meta` - the result is basically the same as if that candidate was deleted.

We did *not* want to be in a state where overload resolution would have to consider the return type. And in any case, the fact that the code here returns `Meta` is immaterial - the problem would also exist if it returned `bool`.

---

Thankfully, the fix here is easy:

```
struct Foo {
    Meta operator==(const Foo&) const;
    Meta operator!=(const Foo&) const;
    //                         ^^^^^^
};
```

Once you make both comparison operators `const`, there is no more ambiguity. All the parameters are the same, so all the conversion sequences are trivially the same. `#1` would now beat `#3` by not by rewritten and `#2` would now beat `#3` by not being reversed - which makes `#1` the best viable candidate. Same outcome that we had in C++17, just a few more steps to get there.

Comment: "*We did not want to be in a state where overload resolution would have to consider the return type.*" Just to be clear, while overload resolution itself does not consider the return type, the [subsequent rewritten operations do](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.oper#9). One's code is ill-formed if overload resolution would select a rewritten `==`and the return type of the selected function isn't `bool`. But this culling doesn't happen during overload resolution itself.

Comment: Its actually only ill-formed if the return type is something that does not support operator !...

Comment: @ChrisDodd No, it has to be exactly `cv bool` (and before this change, the requirement was contextual conversion to `bool` - still not `!`)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my actual problem, but that was because I failed to provide a MRE which actually describes my problem. I'll accept this and when I'm able to reduce my problem properly I'll ask a new question ...

Comment: Looks like a proper reduction for the original issue is https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/tFy4qz

Answer (score 5):

[over.match.best]/2 lists how valid overloads in a set are prioritized. Section [2.8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#2.8) tells us that `F1` is better than `F2` if (among *many* other things):

> `F2` is a rewritten candidate ([over.match.oper]) and `F1` is not

The example there shows an explicit `operator<` being called even though `operator<=>` is there.

And [[over.match.oper]/3.4.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4) tells us that the candidacy of `operator==` in this circumstance is a rewritten candidate.

*However*, your operators forget one crucial thing: they should be `const` functions. And making them not `const` causes earlier aspects of overload resolution to come into play. Neither function is an exact match, as non-`const`-to-`const` conversions need to happen for different arguments. That causes the ambiguity in question.

Once you make them `const`, [Clang trunk compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/7Ehf6N).

I can't speak to the rest of Eigen, as I don't know the code, it's very large, and thus can't fit in an MCVE.

Comment: We only get to the tiebreaker you listed if there are equally good conversions for all arguments. But there aren't: due to the missing `const`, the non-reversed candidates have a better conversion sequence for the second argument and the reversed candidate has a better conversion sequence for the first argument.

Comment: @RichardSmith: Yeah, that was the sort of complexity I was talking about. But I didn't want to have to actually go through and read/internalize those rules ;)

Comment: Indeed, I forgot the `const` in the minimal example. I'm pretty certain that Eigen uses `const` everywhere (or outside class definitions, also with `const` references), but I need to check. I try to break down the overall mechanism Eigen uses to a minimal example, when I find the time.

Answer (score -1):

We have similar issues with our Goopax header files. Compiling the following with clang-10 and -std=c++2a produces a compiler error.

```
template<typename T> class gpu_type;

using gpu_bool = gpu_type<bool>;
using gpu_int  = gpu_type<int>;

template<typename T>
class gpu_type
{
    friend inline gpu_bool operator==(T a, const gpu_type& b);
    friend inline gpu_bool operator!=(T a, const gpu_type& b);
};

int main()
{
    gpu_int a;
    gpu_bool b = (a == 0);
}
```

Providing these additional operators seems to solve the problem:

```
template<typename T>
class gpu_type
{
    ...
    friend inline gpu_bool operator==(const gpu_type& b, T a);
    friend inline gpu_bool operator!=(const gpu_type& b, T a);
};
```

Comment: Was this not something that would be useful to have done beforehand? Otherwise, [how would `a == 0` have compiled](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sDJjGX)?

Comment: This isn't really a similar issue. As Nicol pointed out, this already didn't compile in C++17. It continues to not compile in C++20, just for a different reason.

Comment: I forgot to mention: We also provide member operators: 
`gpu_bool gpu_type<T>::operator==(T a) const;` and `gpu_bool gpu_type<T>::operator!=(T a) const;`
With C++-17, this works fine. But now with clang-10 and C++-20, these are not found anymore, and instead the compiler tries to generate its own operators by swapping the arguments, and it fails, because the return type is not `bool`.