# Implicit operator != resolving ambiguity in operators ==

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer, c++20

If some struct `A` has explicitly declared `operator ==` method, but at the same time there is a global `operator ==` accepting arguments of type `A`, then equality comparison shall result in ambiguity error.

In C++20 we can call inequality `operator !=`, which the compiler will interpret as the negation of equality operator. I though that in the same circumstances ambiguity error shall appear as well, and indeed GCC and Clang show it, but the latest Visual Studio 2019 accepts the code:

```
struct A { 
    bool operator ==(const A&) const = delete; 
};

bool operator ==(const A&, const A&) { return true; }

int main() {
    A a;
    //a == a; //error everywhere
    return a != a; //ok in MSVC
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ds53Wv783

Is it simply a bug in MSVC?

Comment: Hm, this is interesting. I tried to run the exact same code in my local MSVC compiler and it did [give me an error about the ambiguous operator overloads of `operator==`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMcuD.png). I'm not really sure why it doesn't happen in your case but I'm going to take a wild guess here and say that the MSVC compiler that *godbolt.org* uses *might* be broken/outdated in some way or the other.

Comment: I get this error on VS2019 16.10.1: `Error C2676 binary '!=': 'A' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator ConsoleApplication3 + C`. Compiler settings set to C++17 standard. @Ruks what is your version and setting of VS?

Comment: @Jabberwocky VS2019 16.11.2 is the version that I'm currently using. And you need to compile it using C++20 otherwise this code won't compile even if you remove the deleted `operator==` overload to remove the ambiguity. (C++17 doesn't have implicit generation of `operator!=` from `operator==`.)

Comment: Certainly sounds like a MSVC bug.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319928/why-is-operator-removed-in-c20-for-many-standard-library-types

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in MSVC, which is expected to be fixed soon:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/incorrect-acceptable-of-ambiguous-operator/1535876