# If I am implementing operator< in C++, should I also implement operator> and operator==?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If I am implementing `operator <` in a C++ class, should I also implement other comparison operators? (`operator >` and `operator ==` and others)

Or does the class somehow automagically get one from the others?

I want to make my class comparable using STL `std::sort` and `std::priority_queue`.

(note: my class has a `double` member which I am using as an ordering key, so it shares the ordering characteristics of real numbers, which if I understand correctly, makes it a strict total ordering.)

Comment: If you want _automagic_, look into C++20's [`operator<=>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466358/what-is-the-spaceship-three-way-comparison-operator-in-c).

Comment: What you **should** do depends on your use case. Look up the concepts of "partial ordering" and "strict weak ordering".

Comment: What does your C++ textbook say, on this subject?

Comment: wow, the "related questions" are particularly bad today.  I see only one that's relevant ("idioms for operator overloading")

Comment: You should check out [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHxtyCq_WDLXryyw91lahwdtpZsmo4BGD) lectures by Stepanov. Lecture 2 covers semi-regular, regular, and totally ordered types.

Comment: The real answer depends on what comparisons your class is required to support.   If being comparable with `std::sort()` [and only the variant that accepts two iterators] and `std::priority_queue` is the only requirement, then `operator<()` is sufficient.   If code using your class needs to do other comparisons such as `a == b` or `a <= b`, or use other variants of `std::sort()` then you *may* need to implement other operators.   In C++20, there is the spaceship operator, which can reduce need to separately implement a number of operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want your class be comparable for using `std::sort` and `std::priority_queue`, overloading `operator<` is just fine. As stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

`operator<` function does satisfy the requierment. Also the elements are compared by `operator<` if custom comparator is not specified.

> `template< class RandomIt > void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );` (1)

> 1. Elements are compared using `operator<`.

Same applies to `std::priority_queue`.

So in your case, you can do just with `operator<`, if your only requierment is to use `std::sort` and `std::priority_queue`.

However, if you are going to reverse the order with `std::greater`, you will need to implement `operator>`. As stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)

> Function object for performing comparisons. Unless specialized, invokes `operator>` on type T.

However, if you are going only to use `std::greater` to sort the class. You can do it by a little trick. If you implement `operator<` as it was `operator>`, it will do what is intended.

Comment: if I use `std::greater` to reverse the ordering, is `operator<` enough?

Answer (score 1):

Other operators are not automatically generated, although C++20 offers [`operator<=>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319928) which can be used to replace a full set of comparison operators.

However, specifically to make the instances orderable for standard library containers, *only `operator<` is needed*. Even [`std::set` does not require or use operator==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114856).

Even types that don't implement `operator<` can be sorted if a comparison predicate is specified explicitly. But there are not formal interfaces to implement here. standard library template classes and algorithms simply use ad-hoc polymorphism: if the operators *actually used by the library code* are provided, the type is acceptable.

For C++ versions before C++20, it may still be a good idea to implement other comparisons (at least `==`) - since *other* code (possibly your own) might want to use them.

The reason why there is such a mess (optimistically: so much flexibility) here is because *there are conceptually many different meaningful semantics* for these operators. The way that comparisons work for real numbers (and subsets like integers; thus, C++ types `double`, `float`, `int` etc.) is called [*total ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) and is the strictest interpretation. On the other hand:

- Complex numbers can meaningfully be compared for equality, but it's nonsense to say that one is "less than" another when they aren't equal (although their *magnitudes* are real-valued and can be compared that way, for example).
- Sets can meaningfully be "less than" one another (normally this is interpreted as a subset relationship), "less than or equal" etc. - but given two unequal sets, it can be (the common case!) that neither is "less than" the other. This is a [*partial* order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Comment: see update to question re: total/partial ordering; my class objects are ordered based on a `double` member

Comment: Yes, you can implement a total ordering in that case. That doesn't change anything about my answer; implementing the other operators will still be a) trivial; b) not necessary for the described use cases; c) possibly still a good idea. In C++20 just use the new toy and don't sweat it.