# Why can you use a function as an if-statement condition without calling it?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, implicit-conversion

I was wondering why both versions of this code have no error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

bool check_number(int n) {
    return n < 5;
}

int main() {
    int number = 6;

    // (1) prints "Hello World"
    if (check_number)
    // (2) prints "not hello world"
    if (check_number(number))
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world!";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not hello world";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Condition (1) prints `Hello world!` despite the fact that I have not passed the variable `number` into the function `check_number` in the if-statement.

In case (2), I get `not hello world` as expected.

Comment: Why the python tag?

Comment: If you rewrote `if (check_number)` as `if (&check_number != nullptr)`, would you understand why the check evaluates to true?

Comment: Non-member functions in C++ *decay* to pointers to themselves. So on its own `check_number` will be the same as `&check_number`. It will never be a null pointer, and only null pointers are false.

Comment: It has no error but [it sure has a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/x6ePhbaG8).

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Enable treat warnings as errors.  Fix errors.  Problem resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (check_number)
```

In this context `check_number` decays to a *function pointer*, and as the former has an address, the latter is not the null pointer, thus the test succeeds and you enter the `if` branch.

That's just the same as if you assign the function to a function pointer without explicitly taking the address of:

```
bool(*fPtr)(int) = check_number; // don't need &check_number
```

Comment: Would any one explain the down-vote?

Comment: Spite and competition. The answer is fine.

Comment: Don't know why someone would down-vote your correct answer - but I gave you an up-vote to compensate.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks... Just received another DV [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319928/why-is-operator-removed-in-c20-for-many-standard-library-types) – seems pretty much as someone picked me as his target, so I'll probably have to face further meaningless DV :(

Answer (score 8):

`if (check_number) {` is just checking the value of the function pointer against `nullptr` (or `0` and other *null pointer constants*), which is always going to be `true`. It is not calling the function.

Comment: It would be better to say that it's checking whether `check_number` is a null pointer. Checking against zero is indirectly doing the same, but it's a weird way of phrasing it.

Comment: I've corrected it, because `false` is not a null pointer constant, so it wouldn't be possible to compare `check_number == false`.

Answer (score 5):

From the C++ 17 Standard (7.3 Function-to-pointer conversion)

> 1 An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type
> “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the function.

and (7.14 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
> to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
> value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
> to false; any other value is converted to true. For
> direct-initialization (11.6), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
> converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

So in the expression of the if statement

```
if (check_number) {
```

the function designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function and as it is not a null pointer then the expression evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can infer that the condition `(check_number)` does *not* involve a function call because no argument is passed, as you aptly observed.

So in what way can this be valid and behave as a `true` (i.e. nonzero) condition ?

Just by the fact that a function name alone, the same way as an array name alone, is turned to a pointer (to function or to array).